# Normalized character on a non-archimedean local field

Tags: number-theory

I am confused about the term "normalized" for an additive normalized character $\psi$ on a non-archimedean local field.

Does it mean the character would send all the integers to 1?

Thanks!

Comment: Let $\psi(\frac{a}{p^k}+b) = \exp(2i \pi \frac{a}{p^k})$ for $p \nmid a, b \in \Bbb{Z}_p$. Then $\psi$ is a character $\Bbb{Q}_p \to S_1$ and any continuous character $\Bbb{Q}_p \to \Bbb{C}^\times$ is of the form $x \mapsto \psi(yx)$ for some $y \in \Bbb{Q}_p$